# How to obtain a BigInt random number within a range in julia?

Tags: random, julia, arbitrary-precision

I need to obtain a random number between 1 and a `BigInt` in Julia, but I couldn't find out in the documentation how this can be done. The code below is what I thought would work:

```
julia> rand(BigInt(1):BigInt(2^1000))
ERROR: integer division error
 in randu at random.jl:158
 in rand at random.jl:178
 in rand at random.jl:187
```

**edit**: GregS mentioned `2^1000` would wrap around zero. Actually, `2^1000` results in zero, so the code above is wrong. But using `BigInt(2)^1000` doesn't work:

```
julia> rand(BigInt(1):BigInt(2)^1000)
ERROR: InexactError()
 in convert at gmp.jl:108
 in colon at range.jl:38

julia> rand(BigInt(1):BigInt(2)^BigInt(1000))
ERROR: InexactError()
 in convert at gmp.jl:108
 in colon at range.jl:38
```

What is the fastest way to get this done? (Thee numbers should be uniformly distributed).

Thanks!

Comment: That ought to work, please do file an issue.

Comment: I don't know julia but maybe 2^1000 wraps around to zero first. Maybe BigInt(2)^1000 would work better.

Comment: It appears to me this isn't currently supported.  rand(BigInt(1)) results in ERROR: `rand` has no method matching rand(::BigInt), and the Range variant simply tries to compute using the non Range variant.  Can you get by with Int128 until fixed?

Comment: This is a long time after the original post, but `rand(1:big"2"^1000)` now works great for me in Julia 1.1.0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is available after all if you use ccall.  I'm sure at some point it will be eazy, but here's a way to do this now, I did not find a way to use it from base, but will amend if it things change.  There are 2 calls that need to be made for this to work.  From gmp's docs, I chose mpz_urandomm

### GMP Support

> > — Function: void **mpz_urandomm (mpz_t rop, gmp_randstate_t state, const mpz_t n)**
> >     Generate a uniform random integer in the range 0 to n-1, inclusive.
> >
> > The variable state must be initialized by calling one of the gmp_randinit functions (Random State Initialization) before invoking this function.

You must first initialize the random number generator, I did this not optimally, will update with something refined.

> > — Function: void **gmp_randinit_default (gmp_randstate_t state)**
> >     Initialize state with a default algorithm. This will be a compromise between speed and randomness, and is recommended for applications with no special requirements. Currently this is gmp_randinit_mt.

### ccall method

#### Initialize RNG

Not having an elegant way to declare gmp_randstate_t, just declare a big buffer.  This is important otherwise a segfault occurs.

```
julia> buffer = Array(Uint8,32);
julia> ccall((:__gmp_randinit_default,:libgmp),Void,(Ptr{Uint8},),buffer);
```

#### Generate Random Numbers

Create BigInt, x to store the result

```
julia> x = BigInt(0)
0
```

Set y to MaxRange

> > julia> y = BigInt(2)^1000
> >
> > 10715086071862673209484250490600018105614048117055336074437503883703510511249361224931983788156958581275946729175531468251871452856923140435984577574698574803934567774824230985421074605062371141877954182153046474983581941267398767559165543946077062914571196477686542167660429831652624386837205668069376

Generate random x

```
julia> ccall((:__gmpz_urandomm,:libgmp),Void,(Ptr{BigInt},Ptr{Uint8},Ptr{BigInt}),&x,buffer,&y)
```

verify

> > julia> x
> >     9301165293246235069759966068146313776551258669855356477271940698500929939755418247622530571466332330697816620308003246225290293476785304004840090056840661553451916748315356563734257724978000166406621823207925733850455027807451108123161768212073821382033500073069184011344280494573919716117539236653172

etc...

```
julia> ccall((:__gmpz_urandomm,:libgmp),Void,(Ptr{BigInt},Ptr{Uint8},Ptr{BigInt}),&x,buffer,&y)
```

> > julia> x
> >     5073599723113217446035606058203362324610326948685707674578205618189982426100515602680640230141018758328161278469759835943678360952795440512680380424413847653984694781421269745198616340362470820037933917709243387214511018480191308767310495781355601069937334945556566243556239048498564021992916827796124

Answer (score 3):

This is an old post, but Julia now makes it easy to solve this question.

For example, using Julia 1.1.0 (I have customized my Julia REPL for a project I am working on called JulieGo.  The answer should work the same in the regular Julia REPL.)

```
JulieGo>VERSION
v"1.1.0"

# Set seed to get same results again.
JulieGo>rng_info = Random.seed!(12345);

# Here is an answer in Julia 1.1.0.    
JulieGo>r1 = rand(big"1":big"2"^1000)
8986172793045621030349078950793778042482316869955566599310906000510726536023373350273552788410494562
1437227128958537257991121543058284731429268230113459330352619981122924349300809967077942239392386680
0757367867423923215806277494619337596597641816501707643360907546040909561196900772512609868177829183

# Print result in an easy to read format.    
JulieGo>using Printf

JulieGo>@printf "%0.3E" float(r1)
8.986E+299

# Reseed the RNG.
JulieGo>rng_info = Random.seed!(12345);

# Try again.    
JulieGo>r2 = rand(big"1":big"2"^1000)
8986172793045621030349078950793778042482316869955566599310906000510726536023373350273552788410494562
1437227128958537257991121543058284731429268230113459330352619981122924349300809967077942239392386680
0757367867423923215806277494619337596597641816501707643360907546040909561196900772512609868177829183

# The result is the same.
JulieGo>@printf "%0.3E" float(r2)
8.986E+299

JulieGo>r1 == r2
true

# This also works.
# Reseed the RNG.
JulieGo>rng_info = Random.seed!(12345);

# Only the 2 needs to be specified explicitly as a big int.
JulieGo>r3 = rand(1:big"2"^1000)
898617279304562103034907895079377804248231686995556659931090600051072653602337335027355278841049456
143722712895853725799112154305828473142926823011345933035261998112292434930080996707794223939238668
075736786742392321580627749461933759659764181650170764336090754604090956119690077251260986817782918

JulieGo>r3 == r2
true
```